# Display same row between checkbox and text

Tags: flutter

I want to display checkbox and text inline like this image

[image]

But I've issue with multiple `child`. How to arrange position like this image.

`

```
child: Container(
          // child: Row(children: [],),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[500], blurRadius: 3.0, spreadRadius: 1.0),
            ],
          ),
          width: data.size.width * 0.26,
          height: data.size.width * 0.26 * 1.2,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(data.size.width * 0.02),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              // Checkbox(
              //   checkColor: Colors.white,
              //   value: isChecked,
              //   onChanged: (bool value) {
              //     // setState(() {
              //     //   isChecked = value;
              //     // });
              //   },
              // ),
              Text(
                'Title Here',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              AvatarLetter(
                size: 100,
                backgroundColor: getBackColor(),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 40,
                upperCase: true,
                numberLetters: 3,
                letterType: LetterType.Circular,
                text: this.type,
                backgroundColorHex: null,
                textColorHex: null,
              ),
              Text(
                this.Type ?? '',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              Text(
                DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(this.inspectDetails.testDate)).toString(),
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey[400],
                  fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just put them in a `Row` widget like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        // setState(() {
        //   isChecked = value;
        // });
      },
    ),
    Text(
      'Title Here',
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black87,
          fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
    ),
  ],
),
```

If you want to **center** the `text` you can use this `Row`:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Checkbox(
      checkColor: Colors.white,
      value: isChecked,
      onChanged: (bool value) {
        // setState(() {
        //   isChecked = value;
        // });
      },
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Text(
          'Title Here',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black87,
            fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
       ),
    ), 
    Opacity(
       opacity: 0,
       child: Checkbox(
           checkColor: Colors.white,
           value: isChecked,
           onChanged: (bool value) {},
       ),
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: you want to center the text? @Fash

Comment: Yes.., sure... can?

Comment: yes you can, I updated my answer, you need just add a hidden Checkbox on the other side of row.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with a inner Row Element and a Padding element around the Text like so (16.0 is a example value):

```
child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[500], blurRadius: 3.0, spreadRadius: 1.0),
                ],
              ),
              width: data.size.width * 0.26,
              height: data.size.width * 0.26 * 1.2,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(data.size.width * 0.02),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                     children: [
                        Checkbox(
                           checkColor: Colors.white,
                           value: isChecked,
                           onChanged: (bool value) {
                              setState(() {
                                 isChecked = value;
                           });
                       },
                    ),
                    Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                       child: Text(
                          'Title Here',
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                     ),
                  ]),
                  AvatarLetter(
                    size: 100,
                    backgroundColor: getBackColor(),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 40,
                    upperCase: true,
                    numberLetters: 3,
                    letterType: LetterType.Circular,
                    text: this.type,
                    backgroundColorHex: null,
                    textColorHex: null,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    this.Type ?? '',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat('dd MMMM yyyy').format(DateTime.parse(this.inspectDetails.testDate)).toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.grey[400],
                      fontSize: data.size.width * 0.02,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```